# Soft Keyboard settings

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have created a soft keyboard and I want to make settings options for it just like 
**android keyboard** has its setting and **better keyboard 8** has its setting in **language and keyboard settings** section.

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this? I could really do with a positive answer on this now...

Comment: Like @BillyMoon said, it would be nice to update this question with your own answer if you managed something.

Answer (score 1):

You should make preferences for achieve this.Use the blow give url for more about preference in android.

http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences

I hope this is help.